# Can I use IDisposable by treating abstract concepts such as colors as resources?

Tags: c#

There are the following class:

```
class ConsoleForegroundColor : IDisposable
{
    public ConsoleForegroundColor(ConsoleColor color)
    {
        OriginalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    }

    public ConsoleColor OriginalColor { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = OriginalColor;
    }
}
```

This has the following uses:

```
Console.WriteLine("display with default color");
using (new ConsoleForegroundColor(ConsoleColor.Green))
{
    Console.WriteLine("display with green");
}
Console.WriteLine("display with default color");
```

This source code changes the console font color to the specified color when creating an instance and restores it when discarded.

I think it's possible to think of the colors drawn on the console as resources, so I don't think it's so different from the original use of `IDisposable`. Is the use of `IDisposable` like this source code a source that is difficult to understand and maintain? If you have a better think, please tell me.

Comment: Is it the topic of StackOverflow, not here, whether the current IDisposable fits in treating colors as resources? Is Low rating voted come from for it?

Answer (score 2):

Readability-wise, this is fine, though I prefer `ConsoleForegroundBrush`, because it keeps the theme of Drawing library, which is well known, and in the real world, you can definitely destroy/dispose brushes / put them down, but disposing an actual colour would be like... changing the color of the text back to black?

The main issue is there is a performance impact that comes with `using`, as this is really a `try`/`finally` block under the hood, and so you are adding `try`/`finally` around your code which may slow things down unnecessarily, particularly if there's other non-console logic in the using block.

The using block can also sometimes hide other errors, because it's a `try`/`finally` block. If you put a `using` block inside a `try()` block and your `dispose` method of the `ConsoleForegroundColour` class throws an exception (such as if the Console became null somehow), you will probably only see the `Dispose()` exception, and not the other exception. This situation is highly unlikely to happen in your class though.

Comment: I only partially agree: 1) to call it `*Brush` is a nice idea (even if actually it isn't) however 2) `using` is NOT a `try`/`catch` but a `try`/`finally` then no exceptions are thrown (it has a TINY overhead but it's so small that it's not even worthy to mention it). 3) If your `Dipose()` method throws then it's ill-designed: to put it simply...`Dispose()` MUST NOT throw (unfortunately setting `Console.ForegroundColor` might then OP's code MUST be wrapped in a proper `try`/`catch` to catch for `IOException`)

Comment: I have changed comment to use try/finally. The overhead is small as you say, and as the console class is being used, it's unlikely that performance is not a concern - otherwise you'd use something faster that is non-blocking. Still, it is there and worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much what you do contentwise, allocating and freeing a resource is exactly what a  `using` and `IDisposable` is made for.

But the way you do it, is an absolute No-Go.

You do not free ressources contained in your Disposable class. You free ressources in completly different classes, accessed by static properties. And Disposing means "Destroy it" - We don't need it any more. 5 Seconds before self destructions.
It does not mean to Reset something to an original state.

[Your Dispose does not align with the idea of Dispose and is an abuse.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

You should go with a simple try/finally block. This is made for your purpose.

```
Console.WriteLine("display with default color");
var cfc = new ConsoleForegroundColor(ConsoleColor.Green);
try
{
    // do something dangerous
    Console.WriteLine("display with green");
}
finally
{
     cfc.Reset(); // this is your Dispose method, just rename it.
}
Console.WriteLine("display with default color");
```

Your are right, what happens in code, is exactly the same as in your version, but the expectation, what a reader thinks your code does, is completly different.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is generally fine. `Console` is a resource used by your class. You clean up after usage. But your code is far from being perfect and seems to have some design flaws.

You have to check what `IDisposable` is primaryly designed for: to free application resources like memory of *unmanaged* resources. *Unmanaged*  means the garbage collector is not tracking the life cycle of specific object instances and therefore not managing their reserved memory, making them become *unmanaged* instances. 
Also sometimes you have reusable and long living resources, like a database connection instance. You can control the object instance's life cycle yourself. You can use it to make multiple requests without creating a new connection each time, as creating a connection has some overhead and might be expensive.

So, let's say you reuse the connection object instance during each session. When the session ends, you want to end its life cyle too n order to free underlying resources like application memory.
That's when you choose to dispose it. This is where you choose to implement `IDisposable` rather than implementing a `finally`satement `inside` the class which owns the unmanaged resources. This is how you delegate resource management to the client class which is usiing the resource owner. The client class can then decide when to dispose ie. free the unmanaged resources by choosing between a `finally` statement which needs to explicitely invoke `Dispose()` on the resource owner or a `using` statement which implicitely invokes the `Dispose` method after leaving the `using` scope.

But for single isolated operations (method calls) you don't need to dispose the instance since its life cycle is already limited to a single isolated call. In this case you would prefer to use a `finally` statement to clean up after execution of the operation.

```
class ConsolePrinter
{
  public ConsolePrinter(ConsoleColor color)
  {
    this.ConsoleForegroundColor = color;
  }

  private ConsoleColor ConsoleForegroundColor { get; set; }

  public void Print(string message)
  {
    // Remember the current console foreground to immediately revert it after use
    // in order not to interfere with other instances of this class,
    // which might have a differenet foreground set
    var currentConsoleForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;

    try
    {
      Console.ForegroundColor = this.ConsoleForegroundColor;
      Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.ForegroundColor = currentConsoleForeground;        
    }
  }
}
```

This is a far better class design.
From the design perspective:

if the modified value for the static class `Console` is not meant to be global, then set it directly where it is used and reset it right after the operation is completed. Encapsulating the setting of a static class into a seperate class doesn't make sense. It's actually not a color object but a color setter or attribute. It should rather be a property on some class which uses it (see example).

Your current code doesn't forbid to create multiple instances of the class. By your current design each instance would override the color value set by every other instance. So to prevent this it should be a `static` class. But since the original property `Console.ForegroundColor` is alread `static`, you can deduct that your class is a redundant wrapper. You already can set `Console.ForegroundColor` from any scope which leads back to the above example code as the preferred usage.

Also check [Microsoft Docs: IDisposable Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) for a proper implementation of the interface.